# Validate multiple element and value combinations in XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

I am trying to create an XML Schema 1.0 that validates multiple element combinations.

For example,

Is it possible to create a list of possible element - value combination in schema?
Like, 
Valid only if

1. A=1 && B=2
2. A=2 && B=4

**Pass Example**

```
<Full>  
  <A>1</A>
  <B>2</B>      
</Full>  

<Full>
 <A>2</A>
 <B>4</B>
</Full>
```

**Fail Example**

```
<Full>  
  <A>2</A>
  <B>2</B>      
</Full>  

<Full>
 <A>1</A>
 <B>4</B>
</Full>
```

I can't use XML Schema 1.1 yet.
   Is there any good way to put these logic in one schema?

*Sorry about the confusion, I just rewrite my problem again.*

Answer (score 0):

Here Set below things based on your requirement:-

**minOccurs="0"** - for zero occurrances or more than that

**minOccurs="1"** - for minimum one occurrance or more than that

**maxOccurs="unbounded"** : Set this if you want to use infinite times

**maxOccurs="1"** : Set this if you want to only for one time

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="FULL">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="A" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="B" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="C" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

## UPDATED:

Assuming that your are passing all the three separate XMLs, (Not as one whole XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="FULL">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="A" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="B" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="C" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

## Another Update:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="FULL">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="A" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                            <xs:pattern value="[1-2]"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="B" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                            <xs:pattern value="2"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="C" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I am sorry, I guess I didn't state my question correctly. I have edited my question again.

Comment: Your schema will pass the situation when XML only contains <B>2</B>, which I don't want it to pass the schema. I am wondering if schema can set to be just validate against a couple of combinations. like AB, AC and ABC. Not anything else.

Comment: **A** is min & max occurrance is one time.  **B** & **C** are optional but max occurance is one time only.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I am wondering if it's possible to create a list of possible answer instead of counting the occurs. Because the value in the content is also considered. I have add some other cases showing the validate and failed cases.

Comment: Now i have restricted values too, as mentioned in your question. Try it now

Comment: Your "Another Update" will pass when 1. <A>1</A> && <B>2</B>  2.<A>2</A>  && <B>2</B>    This holds one variables. I was trying to ask if it's possible to create a list of combination. For example, <A>1</A> && <B>2</B> pass.    <A>1</A> && <B>3</B> pass.   <A>2</A> && <B>2</B>  pass.    But <A>2</A> && <B>3</B> fail.   So in this case you can't use pattern to solve. Because A can be [1-2] and B can be [2-3], but I just don't want when A=2 B=3 pass.